# How do I add an external container (title) to export in AmCharts4?

Tags: javascript, html, amcharts, amcharts4

I am using AmCharts4 and I want to add the title of the graph which is in an external container with a unique ID to the exported file (image, document, print,...)

This is how I add the title to the container:

```
document.getElementById("uniqID").innerHTML = o;
```

And here is the container:

```
<div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-8 col-lg-8 text-center">
       <div id="122341">
             <a id="uniqID"></a>
       </div>
 </div>
```

For the end result (exported file) I would like for the title to be on top of the document, above the graph.
Please help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

AmCharts does not support adding external HTML into your export. Your title needs to be part of the chart object itself in order for it to get included in the export, e.g.

```
var title = chart.titles.create();
title.text = "My chart title";
```

Comment: I managed to make it work using your code and disabling the tittle. Then on 'exportstarted' event I enable it and on 'exportfinished' event I disable it back.

Answer (score 0):

Check https://www.amcharts.com/docs/v4/concepts/exporting/#Export_options to add the options when export.

```
chart.exporting.title = 'sample';
```

In your case, it will be changed.

```
chart.exporting.title = document.getElementById("uniqID").innerHTML;
```

Comment: This will only work when printing the chart. When I try to add the title to a Image which will be exported it is not working. An example is shown in this [codePen](https://codepen.io/maDness97/pen/abwpJYg)